# Call a javascript function through the use of PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web

In the current example I have a form set up that takes a unique id. There is also a link that takes a unique id. The javascript function will fade in that form when the link is selected. Is it possible to call a javascript function based on the PHP variables used to id the form and the link? And so that it will fade in the correct when that corresponds to the unique id of the form?

PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $form_id = $row[id]; ?><a href="#"
id="askedClick"><?php echo $row[post_text].'<br>'?></a>

<form action="<?php $curent_file ?>"
method="POST" id="<?php echo $row[id] ?>">Do you know the anwer?
    <input type="submit" value="Yes" name="<?php echo $form_id.'yes'?>"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="No" name="<?php echo $form_id.'no'?>" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("phpvariable").hide();
     $("#phpvariable").click(function () {
         $("#phpvariable").fadeIn(1200)
     });
 });
```

Comment: please try to format you code correctly.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code - you have repeating IDs, for instance, since you're using a `while` loop. Additionally, you wouldn't be able to hide based on one ID alone. I would suggest using classes, and use the click event to get the ID of the link clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ids, but it will be much easier to just give your link a class of say "showForm" and use HTML traversal to hide the form that follows it

```
$('.showForm').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('form').first().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: You have to use previousAll too in order to not miss some forms

Comment: @user1073122 Actually we only want siblings after the link, not before,  but you made me realize that we don't want all the forms after the link, just the one immediately following it

Comment: I would prefer to use this method. So I essentially need to set all links to class of ,'showForm', and all forms to id of ,'form'?

Comment: Thee's no need to give your form any class or id. The script just relies on the fact that it should hide the first form following the clicked link. You just have to add a class to the links that should hide the form

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `echo` php statement.  Example below:

```
echo '
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#' . $phpvariable . '").hide();
     $("#' . $phpvariable . '").click(function () {
         $("#' . $phpvariable . '").fadeIn(1200);
     });
 });';
```

Comment: very bad for maintability and viewability

Comment: Using PHP to generate JS is a big PITA, hard to debug, hard to read

Comment: I don't have a problem with it, besides, it answers his question directly.  PHP variables get used in javascript/jQuery all of the time!  It's very common and not anything new.

Comment: Your example does not show all it takes, do you mean to just add that code within the for loop? You should code for others, not for what you think is easy, there are already two others that would prefer not having to deal with it

Comment: @JuanMendes - Questions were:  Is it possible to call a javascript function based on the PHP variables used to id the form and the link? And so that it will fade in the correct when that corresponds to the unique id of the form?  Yes, it's possible.  Provided example in answer of what code question contained.

Comment: Would I place this script inside the actual PHP document?

Comment: @ElmirKouliev - Yes, in the actual PHP document.

Comment: Your solution works, but it would not pass code review around where I work, if you're OK with technically inferior solutions, this is fine.

Comment: I think you'll need to change ` $("' . $phpvariable . '").hide();` to ` $("#' . $phpvariable . '").hide();` however...  gonna update answer now.

Comment: @JuanMendes - Ok, just answered question, that's all.

Comment: and I'm just warning the OP of the downsides of this solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier method of doing this, thought I should I go back and put this in for reference

```
//Javascript
$(".testLink").click(function() {
        var linkId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#testDiv"+linkId).fadeIn(400)
});

//PHP
for ($i = 0;$i < /*whatever*/; $i++){
?>
    <a href="#" class="testLink" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"> Click Here  </a>

    <div style="display:none;" id="<?php echo 'testDiv'.$i ?>" > 
            Unique Data                                                                              
    </div>
<?php
}
```

In this method, a unique id is created between the link clicked, and the element to be manipulated in the javascript. This way each link can be of the same class, but each will have a unique id associated with its corresponding element, i.e div, form, span etc.